# EventHandler error when I try to create a play button for a video media player in Java

Tags: javafx, media, eventhandler

I don't understand why eclipse won't recognize the EventHandler  since I have imported it. Here is my code:
        package application;

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import com.sun.glass.ui.Accessible.EventHandler;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class MediaBar extends HBox {


    Slider time =new Slider();

    Slider vol =new Slider();

    Button playButton=new Button("||");
    Label volume=new Label("Volume");
    MediaPlayer player;

    public MediaBar(MediaPlayer play){
        player=play;

        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setPadding(new Insets(5,10,5,10));
        vol.setPrefWidth(70);
        vol.setMin(30);
        vol.setValue(100);

        HBox.setHgrow(time,  Priority.ALWAYS);

        playButton.setPrefWidth(30);

        getChildren().add(playButton);
        getChildren().add(time);
        getChildren().add(volume);
        getChildren().add(vol);


        playButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                Status status=player.getStatus();

                if(status==Status.Playing){
                    if(player.getCurrentTime().greaterThanOrEqualTo(player.getTotalDuration())){
                         player.seek(player.getStartTime());
                         player.play();
            }
                    else{
                        player.pause();
                        playerButton.setText(">");
                    }
            }
            if(status==Status.PAUSE ||status==Status.HALTED||status==Status.STOPPED){
                player.play();
                playButton.setText("||");
            }

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Here is the error message :

```
The type Accessible.EventHandler is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <ActionEvent>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Correct the import you are using JavaFX not Swing/AWT:

replace :

```
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import com.sun.glass.ui.Accessible.EventHandler;
```

with :

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
```

Avoid automatic importing or pay attention to what you are importing !